# foldr returning a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda

I'm reading [this guide](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) and understand how `foldr` works when we return a number.

```
sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a  
sum' xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs 

ghci> sum' [3,5,2,1]  
11
```

Now I need `foldr` to return a list, and I can't run this code.

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  
map' f xs = foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc) [] xs
```

I don't know what `f` should be.

Comment: Do you know how to use `map`? That `map'` is a reimplementation of normal `map`, and can be used the same way.

Comment: What's your actual question? Since you're reading the guide, you should know about `map` and higher order functions in general.

Comment: @Zeta, I just don't understand `\x acc -> f x : acc`

Comment: `\x acc -> f x : acc` means: apply `f` to `x`, and `cons` the answer to `acc`. So if for example, `f` is `(+1)`, `x` is `0` and `acc` is `[2,3]`, then `f x : acc => (+1) 0 : [2,3] => 1:[2,3] => [1,2,3]`

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev That is [Lambda abstraction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambda_abstraction), and function as an anonymous function.

Comment: As the `map'` signature says, `f` is a function `a->b`. The function could be equivalently rewritten like so: `map' f xs = foldr g [] xs where g x acc = f x : acc`. That's what the lambda abstraction `\x y z -> ...` means

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

```
map' succ [1,2,3]
= foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] [1,2,3]
= foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] [1,2,3]
= (\x acc -> succ x : acc) 1 (foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] [2,3])
= succ x : acc  where x=1 ; acc=foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] [2,3]
= succ 1 : foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] [2,3]
= succ 1 : (\x acc -> succ x : acc) 2 (foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] [3])
= succ 1 : succ 2 : foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] [3]
= succ 1 : succ 2 : (\x acc -> succ x : acc) 3 (foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] [])
= succ 1 : succ 2 : succ 3 : foldr (\x acc -> succ x : acc) [] []
= succ 1 : succ 2 : succ 3 : []
= 2 : 3 : 4 : []
= [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the type:

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] 
map'       f        xs  =  ys   where ys = ...
```

`f` is a function of type `a -> b`:

```
f :: a -> b
f    x =  y   where y = ...
```

meaning, given an `x` of type `a`, it produces a `y` of type `b`. So `map' f` has a type `[a] -> [b]`,

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] 
map'       f        xs  =  ys   where ys = ...
map'       f     :: [a] -> [b]
```

that is, given a list `xs` of type `[a]`, it produces a list `ys` of type `[b]`.

So whatever `f` you're using, it must correspond to the list `xs` with which you intend to use `map' f`: it must accept elements of `xs` as arguments.